# Webpack-dev-server displays listing of "magic html"

Tags: webpack-dev-server

I have a webpack config that I've been using across a few projects. It seems to work fine most of the time, but sometimes, it serves up a list of files instead of the web page. This isn't the same as the normal directory listing; rather, it's referred to as the "magic html for .js". What was interesting is it was very intermittent. I thought it was a browser or configuration issue initially.

### Screenshots:

#### Firefox

[image]

#### Chrome

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While posting this, I noticed that in one address, there is a trailing slash `webpack-dev-server/`, while in the other, there was no slash `webpack-dev-server`. The missing trailing slash was the problem.